# Timeout and 40 msec

Tags: timeout

what can I do to avoid the timeout (40 msec)? I would like to start my script e.g. from January 1st, 2023, because otherwise I would have too much data that would cause the timeout??

I don'u know how it works to start SCript at   at certain time